# previous button and next button is not working in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I had downloaded for this code,it is working but When i am clicking the previous and next image that time it is not working,i dont know what will do...$(".pic img").attr("src", "images/Here i want next image src value");

```
<div class="img-box">
  <ul>
    <?php $query1="SELECT * FROM user_photos_offline" ; $sql=mysql_query($query1); $results=array(); while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ ?>
    <li>
      <img src="images/cropped-images/<?php echo $row['image']?>" />
      <div class="mask">
        <div class="mag">
          <div class="plus"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="full-screen-mask">
  <div class="view-port">
    <div class="pre">
      <span>-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pic"><img /></div>
    <div class="next">
      <span>+</span>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="close">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>


$(".img-box ul li").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  num = index + 1;
  var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  var index = $(this).index();
  //next button function
  function next() {
    $(".pic img").attr("src", "images/"+num+".png");
  }
  $(".next").click(next);
});



//preview button function
function pre(){ 
    $(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png");
    num--;
    if(num==0){
        num=8
    }
}


 $(".pre").click(pre);


//next button function
function next(){ 
$(".pic img").attr("src","images/pic-"+num+".png");
num++;
if(num==9){
num=1
    }
}
 $(".next").click(next);
```

Comment: You don't really have event handlers for those buttons, you just have function called `next()` ?

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake,but not yet working check t now

Comment: I guess the HTML and JS are in separate files or the later one is wrapped in `<script>` tag

Comment: yes i have js in separeate file so no need to script tag,its correct???

Comment: some curly brackets are missing...

Comment: Please post your entire javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts not in tag ,

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check you blocks. It looks like you function next() inside click block.
And you setup listener outside it.

Comment: looks like this is not the answer the questioner is looking for; Anton

Comment: There are bad code styling in example, but it looks like function next inside click function, and setting listener is outside this block.